# Using a QGraphicsItem in a QGraphicsLayout

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to use instances of `QGraphicsItem` such as `QGraphicsRectItem` in a `QGraphicsLayout`. My understanding from the example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-basicgraphicslayouts-example.html#layoutitem-class-definition) is that I should define a class that inherits from both `QGraphicsRectItem` and `QGraphicsLayout`. If I try to do that then `scene.addItem(rect)` causes a segmentation fault, but reversing the order of `QGraphicsLayoutItem` and `QGraphicsRectItem` in the class definition fixes it. This however leads to the same issue when I try to add an instance of this class to a `QGraphicsLayout`. Does it only recognize the inheritance from the first class listed? Do I have to use a different approach due to limitations in Python? If so, what would that approach be?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys

class MyRectItem(QGraphicsLayoutItem, QGraphicsRectItem):
    pass

app = QApplication([])

rect = MyRectItem()

scene = QGraphicsScene()

scene.addItem(rect)

graphics_view = QGraphicsView(scene)

graphics_view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: While I don't know what is occurring in this specific case, multiple inheritance can be affected by the order in which the parent classes are specified: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance. "For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first, left-to-right, ... if an attribute is not found in DerivedClassName, it is searched for in Base1, then (recursively) in the base classes of Base1, and if it was not found there, it was searched for in Base2, and so on."

Comment: The big question: What is the goal of class MyRectItem inheriting from QGraphicsLayoutItem and QGraphicsRectItem? PyQt5 has many limitations on inheritance (it only allows some specific cases). I think you have an XY problem

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm trying to use instances of `QGraphicsItem` in a `QGraphicsLayout` similar to the example in C++ here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-basicgraphicslayouts-example.html#layoutitem-class-definition

Comment: As I have already pointed out, pyqt5 has limitations in inheritance, so the same logic has to be implemented without inherence but perhaps with composition.

Comment: You clearly have an XY problem, your problem is how to implement a Qt example in PyQt5 but instead you ask about a related topic, also in the example it is inherited from QGraphicsItem and not from QGraphicsRectItem

Comment: I have the same issue when I use `QGraphicsItem` instead of `QGraphicsRectItem`.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not sure what an XY problem is.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem